# BeautifulSoup4: parsing bad formatted HTML

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am trying to parse a set of tables listing information about a smartphone mobile. For example [this link](https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_redmi_note_8_pro-9812.php). I am just trying to get 4 specific fields I need, and getting the fourth one is driving me crazy.

It seems that the HTML is badly formatted. We have several tables sequentially placed into the html. The first 5 are ok, but then the sixth table ends with `</td></tr></table>`, closing a `<td>` and a `<tr>` which have not been previously opened (or at least I think this is the problem):

```
<table cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th rowspan="5" scope="row">Memory</th>
<td class="ttl"><a href="glossary.php3?term=memory-card-slot">Card slot</a></td>


<td class="nfo" data-spec="memoryslot">microSD, up to 256 GB (uses shared SIM slot)</td></tr>



<tr>
<td class="ttl"><a href="glossary.php3?term=dynamic-memory">Internal</a></td>
<td class="nfo" data-spec="internalmemory">64GB 6GB RAM, 128GB 6GB RAM, 128GB 8GB RAM, 256GB 8GB RAM</td>
</tr>


<tr><td class="ttl">&nbsp;</td><td class="nfo" data-spec="memoryother">UFS2.1</td></tr>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Also, the seventh table is badly tabulated, but I guess this should not be a problem for bs4.

As a consequence, if I try to use a CSS Selector to get any value from tables 7th to the last one, the selector returns None. In fact, if I just use a selector to get all the tables, it just selects the first 6 tables:

```
        dsoup = BeautifulSoup(dr.content, 'html.parser')
        dsel = dsoup.select('#specs-list > table')
        print('Found {} tables'.format(len(dsel)))  # Prints 6 tables
        dsel = dsoup.select_one('#specs-list > table:nth-of-type(10) > tbody > tr:nth-of-type(3) > td.nfo')
        print(dsel.text.split('\n')) # None
```

So the question is, is there any way of parsing a case of bad formatted HTML like this one, or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `'html.parser'`, but `'html5lib'` - it parses according (most of) HTML5 rules:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.gsmarena.com/xiaomi_redmi_note_8_pro-9812.php'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html5lib')

for th in soup.select('#specs-list th'):
    table = th.find_previous('table')
    for ttl in table.select('.ttl'):
        print('{:<20} {:<20} {}'.format( th.text, ttl.text, ttl.find_next_sibling('td', {'class':'nfo'}).get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')) )
```

Prints:

```
Network              Technology           GSM / HSPA / LTE
Network              2G bands             GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900 - SIM 1 & SIM 2
Network              3G bands             HSDPA 850 / 900 / 1900 / 2100
Network              4G bands             LTE band 1(2100), 3(1800), 5(850), 7(2600), 8(900), 40(2300), 41(2500)
Network              Speed                HSPA 42.2/5.76 Mbps, LTE-A
Launch               Announced            2019, August
Launch               Status               Available. Released 2019, September
Body                 Dimensions           161.4 x 76.4 x 8.8 mm (6.35 x 3.01 x 0.35 in)
Body                 Weight               200 g (7.05 oz)
Body                 Build                Front/back glass (Gorilla Glass 5)
Body                 SIM                  Hybrid Dual SIM (Nano-SIM, dual stand-by)
Display              Type                 IPS LCD capacitive touchscreen, 16M colors
Display              Size                 6.53 inches, 104.7 cm 2 (~84.9% screen-to-body ratio)
Display              Resolution           1080 x 2340 pixels, 19.5:9 ratio (~395 ppi density)
Display              Protection           Corning Gorilla Glass 5
Display                                   500 nits max brightness HDR
Platform             OS                   Android 9.0 (Pie); MIUI 10
Platform             Chipset              Mediatek Helio G90T (12nm)

... and so on.
```